# Is there a way in SQL to aggregate a column across rows and potentially duplicate rows based on another field value in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I have a table, let's call it shipment_items that lists by a shipment_id the individual items contained within a shipment and their quantities.

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| shipment_id |  item_name  | quantity |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|           1 | cleanser    |        1 |
|           1 | moisturizer |        2 |
|           2 | cleanser    |        2 |
|           2 | body wash   |        1 |
|           3 | cleanser    |        1 |
|           3 | moisturizer |        2 |
|           4 | cleanser    |        1 |
|           4 | moisturizer |        1 |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

What I want is to return a table that looks like this

```
+------------------------------------+----------+
|               items                | num_ship |
+------------------------------------+----------+
| cleanser, moisturizer, moisturizer |        2 |
| body wash, cleanser, cleanser      |        1 |
| cleanser, moisturizer              |        1 |
+------------------------------------+----------+
```

Is there any way in sql to do that? I'm thinking something with list_agg, but the tricky part is duplicating the item_names based on the quantity field.   What I'm trying to show in the new table is that there were 2 shipments that contained 2 moisturizers and 1 cleanser, and 1 shipment containing 2 cleansers and 1 body wash.

** EDIT **
Resolved thanks to @Gordon Linoff

new resulting table will look like this

```
+------------------------------------+----------+
|               items                | num_ship |
+------------------------------------+----------+
| cleanser: 1, moisturizer: 2        |        2 |
| body wash: 1, cleanser: 2          |        1 |
| cleanser: 1, moisturizer: 1        |        1 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(item_name, ', ') within group (order by item_name) as items,
       quantity
from t
group by quantity
order by quantity desc;
```

EDIT:

I think you want two levels of aggregation:

```
select items, count(*)
from (select shipment_id,
             listagg(distinct item_name, ', ') within group (order by item_name) as items
      from t
      group by shipment_id
     ) s
group by items
order by count(*) desc;
```

This does not include duplicates in the item list.

EDIT II:

For exact matches, include the quantity:

```
select items, count(*)
from (select shipment_id,
             listagg(distinct item_name || ':' || quantity, ', ') within group (order by item_name) as items
      from t
      group by shipment_id
     ) s
group by items
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: I don't think this returns what I'm looking for exactly.  I edited the post to make it slightly more clear, but I'm trying to group by shipments first, but also duplicate an item_name based on the quantity.  This groups by quantity, which won't tell me how many shipments went out with a specific combination of items

Comment: The edited one is closer, but is there no way to get the duplicates in the item list?  For example if one shipment contained 1 cleanser and 1 moisturizer, I wouldn't want that grouped with 1 cleanser and 2 moisturizers. Just edited the question to add an example of what I mean. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Dan . . . That is just a tweak on the query . . . Include the quantity in the items string.

Comment: Oh that's such a simple solution! and definitely more elegant that what I was envisioning